# Checking Perl version in Apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, perl

How do I check which version of Perl is Apache2 using?  I have a few versions of Perl installed and I want to make sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

perldoc perlvar

$^V contains the version.

perl -le 'print $^V'

Comment: On the command line, simply ask 'perl -v'

Comment: I used the command line only to show sample usage. The contents of $^V is the most trustworthy way of knowing what you're really working with.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't this depend on what your actual scripts have for the shebang line? perl -V I believe would report what perl version the 'perl' command is set up for, but it depends on which one you specify in your scripts.

Are you using mod_perl? .cgi files? How exactly are you using the perl files in Apache?

Answer (score 1):

There should be an entry in the `Server` header sent by your Apache installation to all clients. You can easily check this with a `netcat` session or an [online tool](http://www.webrankinfo.com/english/tools/server-header.php).

For example, our server returns

```
Server: Apache/2.2.9 (Debian) ... mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.0
```

(This may require mod_perl, I'm not certain.)

Comment: The perl version reference is indeed only shown when using mod_perl.